# Windows profile is deleted when user does not log in for several days

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, user-profile

We use a Windows Server 2008 R2 Active Directory network with Windows 7 Professional clients.
After logging in a profile gets created on the computer as normal with all the usual settings, such as the background image, certain preferences and Outlook account settings.

However, if an employee does not login for a certain period of time (I've observed this happening after as few as 11 days) the profile is cleared and the user has to set his/her preferences again.

I have searched the GPO settings to find anything that may have to do with this issue and did not find anything. Also I looked on Google and this website to see if anyone else had this problem, but the only thing I found was users that login at the same time, or roaming profiles that have to be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a GPO setting named `Delete user profiles older than a specified number of days on system restart` under `Computer Configuration|Policies|Administrative Templates|System User Profiles` that may be configured to delete older user profiles. Have a look there.

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems like the answer. The GPO was indeed enabled and configured with 7 days limitation. Just disabled this option and I hope it works.